# Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app while deploying nodejs app on heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, mern, heroku-cli

I tried deploying a MERN app using heroku but getting same error again and again
build log :
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

```
   NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
   NODE_ENV=production
   NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
   NODE_VERBOSE=false
```

-----> Installing binaries
engin`s.node (package.json):  unspecified
engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

```
   Resolving node version 12.x...
   Downloading and installing node 12.20.0...
   Using default npm version: 6.14.8
```

-----> Installing dependencies
Installing node modules
npm ERR! cipm can only install packages when your package.json and package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json are in sync. Please update your lock file with `npm install` before continuing.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Missing: concurrently@^4.0.1
npm ERR!

```
   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
   npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.rBtVz/_logs/2020-12-14T16_46_36_776Z-debug.log
```

-----> Build failed

```
   We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
   
   Some possible problems:
   
   - Node version not specified in package.json
     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
   
   Love,
   Heroku`enter code here`
```

!     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
!     Push failed

```
enter code here
```

if anyone could help
thanks in advance

Comment: this may be a stupid question, but did you follow this step: `Please update your lock file with npm install before continuing`

Comment: yes i did 
after that same error